# Controlled character teleport and get stuck halfway in the floor

Tags: unity-game-engine

im a beginner in unity and recently i started watching youtube tutorials to get preferences on how to do animation
to be more precisely, im watching this series of tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UdUi7-SsP3I&list=PLfxIz_UlKk7IwrcF2zHixNtFmh0lznXow&index=3

i followed mostly every steps but some of them i can see was probably because of the different in version, and i wasn't able to follow through and have to try and work around

but when i start adding the jump input this problem start to show

[Currently in play mode and got stuck after just a few steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPoM3.png)

before the jump input, the character was working fine it can walk and run around perfectly, but after that the character start teleporting to the floor and froze. now even if i try to reverse the code it still doesnt work.

i have also read through the comments and there are some people having the same problem as my but none have a definite answer.

**Edit:**

This gonna sound stupid but after i turn off unity and a night sleep it work fine again without doing anything. Still dont understand why it happend though

Answer (score 0):

Sure looks like an animation offset problem to me. I've had this happen a bunch of times before. I'd try the following in this order, testing after each one:

1. On the jump animation, set Rig > Avatar Definition to "Create from this Model"
2. On the jump animation, in the Animation tab, tweak the jump animation clip's Root Transform Y Offset and apply until it looks right. I'd go +-.5f to start.
3. If neither of the previous steps work, download fresh animations from Mixamo. Unity has updated since the release of the tutorial, so it might import the original project files differently than how they were imported in the video.